# Why is a proof resolved this way using Gentzen elimination?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am trying to get my head around [Gentzen's Natural Deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction). An example is provided to prove that $B \wedge A \implies A \wedge B$:

```
[B & A]z          [B & A]z
------- &-E1      -------- &-E0
   A                 B
   ------------------- &-I
          A & B                     [B]y   [A]x
    ------------------ =>-Iz         ----------- &-I
    (B & A) => (A & B)                 B & A
    ---------------------------------------- =>E
                      A & B
```

1. What is the meaning of `z` in `[B & A]z`? Same story for `x` in `[A]x`?
2. Why does `z` appear in one place, disappear and then reappear in another?

### Why

Since we want to prove $B \wedge A \implies A \wedge B$, consider the first block:

```
[B & A]z          [B & A]z
------- &-E1      -------- &-E0
   A                 B
   ------------------- &-I
          A & B
```

3. Isn't this sufficient? We have proved it! Why going even further?

Comment: $z$ and $x$ keep track of the discharges assumption.

Comment: Having said that, you are right: 2 is the correct derivation; $(B \land A) \vdash (A \land B)$. Then you use $(\to \text E)$ to discharge the assumption to get: $\vdash (B \land A) \to (A \land B)$

Comment: Thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA. I have edited the question with another point.

Comment: $(\to \text I)z$ means that in the step with the use of $\to$-Introduction rule you has discharged assumptions labelled $z$.

Comment: The example provided does not discharge the assumptions labelled $y$ and $x$, so actually proves $\sf B, A \vdash A\mathop\& B$